# 60s/70s short story: man trapped in lunar cave by military robot

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story I remember reading in the 1980s.
It concerns a man trying to deactivate a military robot which has remained active after the end of a war, due to damage to its communications equipment(?). It attacks him and he takes refuge in a cave. At one point his spacesuit is damaged and he fills the leg with water and freezes it. I think it is set on Earth's moon, but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Is it this one? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141156/robot-tank-run-amok-its-trainer-trapped-in-cave-on-the-moon

Comment: You can read it here: https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v53n01_1954-03_cape1736/page/n53

Comment: That's the one, thanks