# Book Title from 1970's-1980's - Military SciFi Collection of Tank Short Stories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, military-sf

Looking for title of collection of short-stories involving tank/tank battles.  Pretty sure it had a tank on the front cover.

Two distinct stories I remember:

#1: Injured soldier stuck in a cave on Mars (or another planet) has verbal back-and-forth with a malfunctioning sentient tank that is just out of kill-shot range.  The story ends when the tank realizes it can disable safe-guards, get a running start, and lob a shell/grenade the extra 50ft needed to kill the human.  Tank registers satisfaction that the annoying radio emissions from the human have stopped.

#2: Enhanced super-soldier has been retired/exiled to a remote security enclosure out in the wilderness.  Society used him for combat, then discarded/were afraid of him after the war.  A female assassin-type somehow eludes security protocols and gains entrance to his compound.  We realize that she's there because the super-soldier killed her brother - who was a brain-in-a-tank, on the other side during the war.  Lots of back-story, regrets, enlightenment, etc.  She dissapears one morning, leaving the device that allows the super-soldier to escape his confinement.

Comment: This is the first story; ["I Made You" by Walter Miller](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141156/robot-tank-run-amok-its-trainer-trapped-in-cave-on-the-moon)

Comment: It was collected in a lot of different books about robots and tanks; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55872

Comment: Yes, that's it!  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably "[Supertanks](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?33858)"

[image]

It contains the story [I Made You](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55872) already id'd by Valorum, and has a tank on the front cover.

The other story is [Encounter](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?66156) by Stephen Leigh.  It has the enhanced soldier exiled to an enclosure and the female warrior who comes after him. She, her husband, father, and brother were all "animatanks during the war...our brains wired to the machinery while our bodies slumbered at home." The enhanced soldier killed the husband and brother and "crippled my father and me".

Comment: I may be confabulating two separate short stories in separate books.  But "I Made You" was at least one I was looking for.  Many thanks.

Comment: @user3208998 No, you were correct, I figured it out, the 2nd story is "Encounter", it's in the book. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Now should we close the older question (about just one of these two stories) as a duplicate of this one, even though the older Q and A both have more detail? (cc @Valorum)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'd say no, because this is asking for *the title of an anthology*, not a story.  I did not find any other questions on the site where "Supertanks" was the answer, so does not seem like a duplicate to me.

Comment: Yup. Not a duplicate.